# Static analysis CA1811 error on Test methods with lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, static-analysis

I found a strange Visual Studio static analysis error while writting my test. The code bellow generates [CA1811](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182264.aspx) on both test methods `FailCA` and `PassCA`.

> 'ClassToTestTests.FailCA()' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.
>   'ClassToTestTests.PassCA()' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.

Code:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using static Namespace.ClassToTest;
using static NUnit.Framework.Assert;

namespace Namespace {
    public static class ClassToTest {
        public static object MethodToTest (object value) => value;
        }

    [TestFixture]
    internal sealed class ClassToTestTests {
        private object value = new object ();

        [Test]
        public static void FailCA () => Throws<ArgumentNullException> (() => MethodToTest (null));

        [Test]
        public void PassCA () => Throws<ArgumentNullException> (() => MethodToTest (value));
        }
    }
```

If I comment `FailCA`  or change code of it to something like this

```
[Test]
public void FailCA () {
    value = null;
    Throws<ArgumentNullException> (() => MethodToTest (value));
}
```

Then warning dissapears for **both** methods. So it seams that `() => MethodToTest (null)` has something to do with this.

Any ideas why warnings are generated for all methods?

Comment: Your class is internal, so the public functions can only be called from within the assembly - but this is not done anywhere, so it is considered dead code - thus the warning.

Comment: @Aconcagua I know what CA1811 means. My question is why it is generated only when i have `FailCA` method. Warning is not generated if I comment that method out.

Comment: If you comment it out, there is no dead code, so no warning. Interesting part is making it non-static: A static method is independent of any class instances (and thus has no implicit this). Such a static method is expected to be called somewhere from within the assembly, if not accessible from outside. Non-static methods are bound to the existance of an object. Apparently, there is no check if such an instance is ever created, so a decision, if dead code, cannot be made either, thus no warning.

Comment: Removing `static` from `FailCA` does not change anything. I understand why commenting `FailCA` removed warning "'ClassToTestTests.FailCA()' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers." But how come **both**? `FailCA` does not have any afect on `PassCA`.

Comment: Plus, can you explain why warning is no longer generated if I change `() => MethodToTest (null)` to `value = null; Throws<ArgumentNullException> (() => MethodToTest (value));`? This does not change the fact that the `FailCA` is never called?

Comment: Ah, got it. You're right, this is strange. And for now, I have no explanation. Will have do dig deeper, but cannot do this right now...

Comment: Why you bother? It's event documented in the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182264.aspx) you posted: "*This rule can report **false positives** if entry points occur that are not currently identified by the rule logic.*" :)

Comment: @IvanStoev just interested what's so special about `() => MethodToTest (null)` that it generates these warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup code analysis with all rules enabled. Perhaps you have CA1812 suppressed because it would appear on most NUnit test fixtures since they're dynamically called by the framework. Either way:

With your code, I get the 2 warnings that you've listed in your question. When I comment out FailCA or make it non-static then I don't get those warnings. However I do get another warning instead:

> Warning   CA1812  'ClassToTestTests' is an internal class that is apparently never instantiated. If so, remove the code from the assembly. If this class is intended to contain only static methods, consider adding a private constructor to prevent the compiler from generating a default constructor.

So, the reason your original warning disappears is because the code analyzer has already determined that the whole class is never instantiated and has no static methods so it need not bother to check if each method inside the class has been called.

When you uncomment FailCA, the fact that there is a static method means that it needs to check the methods for callers even though it knows that the class is never instanced.

Comment: It seams that I actually had CA1812 disabled (don't know why that happened). Then this actually makes sence.